# h5py viewer not able to open it / call programmatically

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have been creating a dataset (which involves images and metadata) using h5py.

But, I want to check how the data is represented in the file. And whether it is correct or not.

I found https://pypi.org/project/h5pyViewer/ which has a good UI. But, when I try to run, it throws a syntax error (the library is built with Python 2.x) and I am not able open the application even though I switched my Python version.

It doesn't have good documentation as well. Are there any other applications for viewing HDF5 data? Or, how can we solve the issue with h5pyViewer and use it?

Comment: Depending on what you need to see, our [h5glance](https://pypi.org/project/h5glance/) tool could be a lightweight option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Use **HDFView** from **The HDF Group**. It is Java based and doesn't have any Python dependencies. It has a nice GUI (IMHO).
You can download HDFView binaries for Win-7, Win-10 and Linux here (you need to create a login to access):
[HDFView Software Download](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/)

Alternately, you can try **ViTables**, which is also Python based (so has dependencies). It's nice if you want to run queries on your data. More info here:
[ViTables Overview](http://vitables.org/)
ViTables source and wheel packages are available here:
[ViTables at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vitables/files/ViTables-3.0.0/)

Comment: Thanks @kcw78!! ViTables works fine. I have already tried HDFView before.